# Power Apps more than two levels filtering

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am building canvas Power App with Sharepoint as a data base. It is employee data with hierarchical structure based on manager personal ID. Hierarchy can be up to 6 levels. List has column "Approved". Data in the Power App is personalised and manager can see only organisation under him.

I need to be able to count how many employees are approved in the manager organisation. So if manager have five levels under him, I need to loop through all those 5 levels and check if value of the column approved is "Yes".

I can easily do it with two levels down by using nested galleries, but since power apps do not support more than two levels, I'm hitting a wall here.

Anyone had worked on something similar and could guide on how to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

These requirements are best achieved in Power BI. It has purpose-built functionality for all your points:

1. Map organizational hierarchy = Path, PathItem functions
2. Filter data based on identity = Manage Roles, UserPrincipalName function
3. Count items matching criteria = Card visualization
4. Display data in multiple hierarchy levels = Pivot visualization
5. (not mentioned but let's assume you also need to handle the approval actions) = ability to embed PowerApps in Power BI report

If you need to do it in PowerApps anyway, you can look into displaying data with a HTML Text function (it will be less interactive, but can look great). You will still have to tackle the org mapping, perhaps with the `Group()` and `AddColumns()` functions can help here.